# Irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials via schemes

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

A few months ago, someone told me there existed a scheme theoretic proof of the irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials. I've tried coming up with a proof, and when that didn't really yield anything $($just the scattered thoughts I have below$)$, I searched online for a reference to a proof, to no avail. Can anyone provide a proof or a reference to one? Does a proof even exist via schemes, or was this someone trolling me? Would this question be a better fit on MathOverflow?

Here are my thoughts so far on such a proof, if it were to exist.

The standard linear algebraic $($or in context of "modern" frameworks, the "$p$-adic"$)$ formulation of the irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials is as follows.

**Theorem.** Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}$ is $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}] = \phi(n)$.

This is saying is that the vector space generated by the powers of $\zeta_n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is of dimension $\phi(n)$. The most important case in the proof is where $n = p$, where one shows that the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ has dimension $p-1$. This is done by showing $$\dim_\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)) = \dim_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]) = \dim_{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]/p),$$and that $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]/p) = p-1$.

Now, the purpose of scheme theory is to make geometry out of rings. In the case of this elusive proof, I imagine the scheme theoretic perspective claims that the extension of rings $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]/\mathbb{Z}$ is like a ramified cover of topological spaces. One imagines $\mathbb{Z}$ as space populated by its primes, and similarly for $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$. The scheme theoretic restatement of the above theorem is that this is a connected cover of degree $\phi(n)$. In the standard proof of the linear algebraic formulation above one sees this by looking above the prime $p$, where one sees "nilpotency" of order $p-1$, which implies that the cover must have degree $p-1$.

Is this viable? Should I use some sort of monodromy or something? $($But that's harder to make sense of in the arithmetic setting...$)$

Comment: You have the basic idea, I think. Let $X = \text{Spec }\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ and $Y = \text{Spec }\mathbb{Z}$. The idea is that the associated morphism $f:Y\to X$ is a finite map of some fixed degree; the degree of the map is precisely the degree of the extension. So if you can compute the degree of a fiber, then you know the degree of the map. There is a sort of monodromy action happening too, namely the action of the Galois group on the fibers of $f$.

Comment: I doubt there is no proof that is not ridiculously difficult, and is not just the standard proof. While you may be able to phrase it more geometrically, algebraic geometry of affine schemes is just commutative algebra.